# How to validate inclusion of time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => TimeZone
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => Time.zone
```

This error appears:

```
"<class:User>": uninitialized constant User::TimeZone (NameError)
```

I'm trying to let users select any time zone of the world but since I'm based in the U.S.A. my select menu is this:

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, {:prompt => "Select Your Time Zone *"}, {:id => "timezone"} %>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select the option with value `"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` this string is going to be passed to the model for validation. Your `validates_inclusion_of` is going to run `Enum`'s [`.include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) method on the collection you pass with `:in`.

Neither `Timezone` and `Time.zone` extend `Enum` to my knowledge, so they will *not* return an `Enum` instance that `.include?` will return true/false for.

If your select consists of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones`, this is what you should be checking the inclusion validator against

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones
```

But as `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones` doesn't return strings, one way you could get a common type for comparison is casting the above `Enum`'s contents to strings.

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)
```

With this, a selected value like `"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` should evaluate `true`, as the following does in console without trouble.

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s).include?("(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
=> true
```

Answer (score 5):

I think here is a better solution:

```
validate :time_zone_check
def time_zone_check
  # I allow nil to be valid, but you can change to your likings.
  if time_zone && ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(time_zone).nil?
    errors.add(:time_zone)
  end
end
```

The reasons are:

1. Rails caches existing TimeZone objects, which `new` uses. So using it to lookup objects will not create extra objects. (`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)` definitely will)
2. If you happen to import time_zone from else where (such as browser user-agents), you will get TZInfo identifiers, which may not be in `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all`. The related issue is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7245

Answer (score 1):

you could use

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:name)`
or 
`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map{ |tz| tz.tzinfo.name }`

to list the time zone in the select menu and you could add a similar custom validation mentioned above. Like,

`validate  :check_timezone`

```
def is_proper_timezone
  errors.add(:time_zone, 'invalid') unless ActiveSupport::TimeZone[time_zone]  
end
```